# "npm run eject" ejected succcessfully, but followed by "The batch file cannot be found."

Tags: react-native, npm

I created a fresh project with `create-react-native-app`.However, when running `npm run eject`, it shows **Ejected successfully!**, but followed by

```
[15:29:29] Ejected successfully!
The batch file cannot be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ eject: `expo eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02- 06T09_59_29_832Z-debug.log
```

npm version: v8.11.2

Comment: In the issues log [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/469#issuecomment-410106125) it suggests _"Delete the iOS and Android folder before trying again"_ - may be worth trying.

Comment: @RobC its not working;shows error `npm ERR! missing script: eject`